# Query Cosmos for records on a specific date

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Using Azure Cosmos db, I have the following data...

[image]

What would be the SQL query to return all records that match the date '2/29/2020' (irrespective of the time value)?

I have tried something like this (found it on another SO post), but it gives a syntax error.

```
select c.* from c where c.ReadingDate BETWEEN '2020-02-29' and '2020-02-29'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [STARTSWITH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-startswith) function to match the date portion:

```
SELECT * FROM c where STARTSWITH(c.ReadingDate, "2020-02-29")
```